# Java 1.6: Sorting a List of models basel on a model value

Tags: java, algorithm, search, collections

I am using java 1.6. I have a `Employee` model as shown below:

```
private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phoneNumber;
//getters and setters
```

The `List<Employee>` contains all the employee data fetch from the DB.

I need to search for one or more employees present within the `List<Employee>` (something like a employee search functionality, search has to be done on the `List<Employee>` rather than another DB hit with search criteria). As of now, I don't want any DB hit for searching the employee from the `List<Employee>`. But if it becomes complicated then I have to go for the db hit.

Right now whatever I have thought of is a sluggish logic like: Iterate through the `List<Employee>` and for each `Employee` keep on searching for the values of search criteria, if it matches then add it to a new `List<Employee>` (this will give me the search result).

I want to know if there is some optimal way of achieving the same. Please let me know about this.

Comment: You can try implementing binary search. For sorting the list you can make your employee class implement Comparable interface.

Comment: What has this to do with servlets and web-services?? Further, the title speaks of "sorting", and the question speaks of filtering.

Comment: You can create your own indexes. Each index would be a `Map` with the keys being the values you would like to search on and the values being the `Employee` objects. It depends on the tradeoff you want to make between time up front, memory space used and time for each search. Consider how many employees there are, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

```
class EmployeeComparator implements Comparator<Employee>{

   public int compareTo(Employee o1,Employee o2){
       return o1.lastName.compareTo(o2.lastNam);
   }

}
```

and:

```
Collections.sort(listOfEmplyees, new EmplyeeComparator);
```

But I don't understand, how this will help by your searching. At least it is sorted now.